# How to set `testOptions in Test` when using scct

Tags: sbt, scalatest, scct

In sbt, I can pass arguments to ScalaTest using `testOptions in Test += Tests.Arguments("...")` as described [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt).

Is there a way to pass these options through [scct](https://github.com/mtkopone/sbt-scct) to ScalaTest when calling `scct:test`?  I tried `testOptions in Scct += ...` but it seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scct looks like it has two configurations: `ScctTest` and `Scct`.  [From the source](https://github.com/mtkopone/sbt-scct/blob/master/src/main/scala/ScctPlugin.scala#L48), you probably want `testOptions in ScctTest`